# Solving for the Integration Limit for a Gamma Random Variable

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

The probability of an event $T$ is given by:

$$ P_{T} = \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}^{\infty} T^{\alpha-1}e^{\beta T}dT$$

Given that I know $P_{T}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$, how can I solve for $\gamma$?

I know if $T$ is Gaussian distributed, it is possible. But what if $T$ is Gamma distributed as it is here?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to compute this [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition) without a computer/table, similar to the situation for the Gaussian CDF ([error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)).

Answer (score 0):

As written in the post, the integration requires that $$\Re(\beta )<0\land (\gamma >0\lor \gamma \notin \mathbb{R})$$and the problem finally reduces to finding the zero of$\gamma$
$$f(\gamma)={\Gamma (\alpha ,\beta  \gamma )}-P_T\,{\Gamma (\alpha )}$$ which requires numerical methods (just as  angryavian already commented).

From a practical point of view and for numerical efficiency, it would probably be better to find the zero of $$g(\gamma)=\log\left({\Gamma (\alpha ,\beta  \gamma )} \right)-\log\left(P_T\,{\Gamma (\alpha )} \right)$$ which is more linear (making Newton happier).